# Angular 1.5: How to pass async data to child component

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, d3.js

I'm trying to pass async data to child d3 component to draw chart.

```
parentComponent.controller = function(){
  this.data = null;
  this.$postLink = function () {
    console.log('postlink')
    async(url).then(function(data){
        this.data = data;
    }.bind(this))
  }
}

childComponent({
  bindings: {
    data: '<'
  },
  controller: function(){
    this.$onInit = function () {
        console.log('init')
        console.log(this.data)
    }

    this.$onChanges = function () {
        console.log('onchange')
        console.log(this.data)
    }

    this.$doCheck = function () {
        console.log('docheck')
        console.log(this.data)
    }
  }
})
```

Log looks like this:

```
onchange null
init null
docheck null
postlink
```

But it works if I change parent data synchronously.

```
this.$postLink = function () {
    console.log('postlink')
    this.data = 'new data';
}

// logs
.
.
.
postlink
docheck 'new data'
onchange 'new data'
```

Can someone please tell me why this is not working and how to make d3 angular component?

Comment: What is async()? Angular doesn't know that the model has changed if you modify it "behind its back", i.e. without using one of its services like $timeout, $interval or$http. You need to call $scope.$apply() in that case.

Comment: how is your html structure are you passing data into child component? please paste that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `$q.when` method to convert the suspicious promise to a $q service promise.

```
parentComponent.controller = function($q){
  this.data = null;
  this.$postLink = function () {
    console.log('postlink')
    //USE $q.when
    $q.when(async(url)).then(function(data){
        this.data = data;
    }.bind(this))
  }
}
```

$q Service promise `.then` methods are integrated with the AngularJS digest cycle so that changes to the model will automatically update controllers and the DOM.

> ### when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.
>
> [-- AngularJS $q Service API Reference - when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like either $q or $http or $parentScope.digest() can make it work!

Comment: Using `$q.when` is safer. Manually invoking `$digest` risks [Error: $rootScope:inprog](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog). Also there are hard to debug errors created if the watchers on a particular scope modify the model outside the scope of the digest. Be careful of taking any advice that recommends using `$digest`.